# google map predictive location search issue in firefox

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-places-api

first go to this link http://www.enjoyholistic.com/event/search
and fill the search form and click search and in post code textbox enter london.

If I go to the event detail screen and return back to the search, it doesn't populate the location. If I click the location box- postCode,Town,city search.
it magically appears.

I will use below code to populate textbox.

```
(function ($) {
$.QueryString = (function (a) {
    if (a == "") return {};
    var b = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
        var p = a[i].split('=');
        if (p.length != 2) continue;
        b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }
    return b;
})(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
})(jQuery);

 $("input[name='eventPostCode']").val($.QueryString["eventPostCode]);
```

it will work in chrome but dont work in firefox...

refer this site
http://www.enjoyholistic.com/event/search

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are either something wrong in the javascript or just the nature of firefox that the places-api does not get notify when it go back by a back button.

I cannot find doc regarding to how to do this but I think one workaround might be to change focus in and out of the places autocomplete text box.

You can do this by using `document.getElementById("autocomplete-text-box").focus();` and `document.getElementById("autocomplete-text-box").blur();`